# Setting EObject's resource with a command

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-emf

I'm using a TransactionalEditingDomain to manage changes on my model. However, I have some problems in creating an empty model. I think that the problem is when I add the model to the model Resource (`modelResource.getContents().add(model);`), because it should be put within  a transaction. Accordingly, I was trying to use the `AddCommand` to perform such operation, but I am not able to find a `EStructuralFeature` for the Resource's `contents`.

In other words, I would like to write something like:

```
Command cmd = AddCommand.create(editingDomain, modelResource, FEAT_CONTENTS, model);
commandStack.execute(cmd);
```

The problem is that I cannot find the `FEAT_CONTENTS`... does anybody have a suggestion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the "official" solution with using AddCommand on the [Eclipse Forum of EMF](https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=208581&goto=668323&#msg_668323):

```
Command cmd = new AddCommand(editingDomain, modelResource.getContents(), model);
commandStack.execute(cmd);
```

Since removing a root object is also non-trivial, the same approach can be used with RemoveCommand:

```
Command cmd = new RemoveCommand(editingDomain, modelResource.getContents(), model);
```

Finally, for completeness, you should also know that DeleteCommand (that also removes all references to the removed object) does not work on root objects at all.

Comment: Awesome! I cannot test it, as I moved to a different project.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, but sincerely I do not like it:

```java
commandStack.execute(new RecordingCommand(editingDomain) {
    protected void doExecute() {
        modelResource.getContents().add(model);
    }
});
```